# Convert faulty unicode string to bytes

Tags: python-3.x

In python 3 I have string u'\xf4\xfb\xe2' (unicode). I need convert this string to bytes b'\xf4\xfb\xe2' (i.e. u'\xf4' -> b'\xf4' etc.).
I can get this result in Python 2 using:

```
''.join([chr(ord(c)) for c in u'\xf4\xfb\xe2'])
```

But in Python 3 chr() return unicode.
How can i do this in Python 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bytes(map(ord, u'\xf4\xfb\xe2'))
```